# How to properly merge a git branch with rebase, given the errors below in my question?

Tags: git

Using `git` I ran again in some issues. I wanted to merge a branch to `master` using bitbucket, but the automatic `merge` button again did not work.

The error says

```
The merge could not be completed automatically. Please clone 'MyRepo', checkout 'master' and merge 'mybranch' (or commit 'd58f55892e3e70cdbc1d4f2d71fdf57639fa420c') manually, resolving any conflicts, and push the result.
```

So I ran the following commands:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout mybranch
git pull
git rebase master
```

Of course I get conflicts and resolved them to the best of my knowledge. After having resolved the conflicts I ran the command

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

because I do not want to create a new commit. After that I tried  a

```
git push --force
```

which resulted in an error

```
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
state now, use
git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

which I have no idea what it means. But I used the suggested command and did

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

which did not work and then again

```
git push --force origin HEAD:master
```

That seem to have worked, but the commit message is wrong. It says now

```
 Merge branch 'master' of ssh://...
```

What should I have done differently at what stage to create a proper merge?

Comment: But this is what the bitbucket error says. Error output added on top of the question.

Comment: Oh sorry! I misread the bitbucket message...

Comment: Yes I know they matter. I made a mistake. It is my fault. You are correct. I am wrong. I am sorry about this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sequence is just a lot of wasted blather:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout mybranch
git pull
git rebase master
```

All those pulls are just silly. The way to update everything is to say `git fetch`. So, assuming you are on `mybranch`, you should have said:

```
git fetch origin master:master
git rebase master
```

Except that you shouldn't, because the way to fix a forward merge conflict is to first do a reverse merge and fix the conflict there. So the correct incantation was in fact

```
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

That would have set off the merge. You resolve the conflicts, saying `git add <FileIJustResolved>` after editing and fixing each conflicted file, and then end up with `git merge --continue` to finish off.

You then push, and now, back on Bitbucket, the merge will work, because the conflicts have been resolved.

Notice that I said `git merge origin/master`. That is the thin edge of the wedge of me telling you that you *should not have a local `master` branch at all*. All it's doing is adding extra steps and confusing you. I would suggest that you just delete it.

Comment: I just tried it and in the `git merge --continue` it asks me for a new(?) commit message? Why? I just want to use the old one. Maybe I can do `git merge --continue --amend --no-edit` or something?

Comment: Git `merge` makes a merge commit. It needs a commit message. You can put any message you like. I usually say something like "merge master to fix conflicts".

Comment: But I want to merge the commit from the branch onto master. A commit which has already a commit message. But anyway. After the `git merge --continue` I do just `git push --force master`? What is the last step?

Comment: I think I answered that already.

Comment: No I don't think so. It is not part of your answer.

Comment: What about the sequence "end up with `git merge --continue` to finish off. _You then push_, and now, _back on Bitbucket, the merge will work_, because the conflicts have been resolved"?

Comment: The explicit command I guess is `git push --force`. Thank you

Comment: No. If you have to use force, you didn't do what I said. It sounds like you rebased. I said not to. That is the whole point of my answer. You didn't do what Bitbucket said. You didn't do what I said. You did not follow directions and then you complain that the directions did not work.

Comment: But still, the bitbucket "instructions" are extremely sparse. Only with extended knowledge of git you are able to run what bitbucket cannot do automatically. And yes, I KNOW that I was WRONG! How often do I have to repeat that?

Answer (score 1):

From what I read, you got lost at this step:

> Of course I get conflicts and resolved them to the best of my knowledge.

The way a rebase works is that it rewinds your `mybranch` to the ancestor commit which is in common with `master`.  Then it applies any *new* commits occurring in `master` from that common commit.  Finally, it *reapplies* your commits from the `mybranch` branch since that common commit.  If you did encounter any merge conflicts, you should have been prompted to resolve all conflicts and then type the following:

```
git rebase --continue
```

You *might* have to do this for each reapplied commit, assuming each commit resulted in merge conflicts.  You should *not* have to manually do any commit, as Git will reapply all commits automatically as part of the rebase process.

The workflow you should have followed would look something like this:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout mybranch
git rebase origin/master
# Git rewinds the branch, applying new master commits
# Then Git reapplies your mybranch commits one by one
# if any conflicts, resolve manually, and then type
git rebase --continue
```

After this, the rebase should be complete.

Comment: I tried the documentation on `rebase`  but this is just too complex for me

Comment: What I need is a precise workflow I can follow

Comment: @Alex note the difference between this answer and matt's answer is simply a personal/team preference. I tend to prefer this answer when resolving conflicts on personal branches (like in your case in the question), and would use matt's answer when resolving conflicts for merging one shared branch into another.